# How do I resolve a dependency during ConfigureServices?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Given this example implementation of `ConfigureServices`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{           
    services.AddSingleton<SomeComponent>();

    services.AddMvc(config =>
    {
        config.OutputFormatters.Add(new CustomFormatter(/* HELP! */));
    });
}
```

I need to pass an instance of `SomeComponent` (hopefully only a single one will exist) to the constructor of my custom formatter. How can resolve such an instance from within the `ConfigureServices` implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the service provider in advance and use it like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<SomeComponent>();

    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var item = provider.GetService<SomeComponent>();

    services.AddMvc(config =>
    {
        config.OutputFormatters.Add(new CustomFormatter(item));
    });
}
```

Comment: To be honest I think it'd be more correct to resolve the service from within the configuration delegate passed to `AddMvc`.

Answer (score 1):

I know that some developers see the service locator pattern as an anti-pattern.  But there are cases where it's the right tool for the job. This is probably one of those cases. You could solve your issue like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, 
                              IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
{           
    services.AddSingleton<SomeComponent>();

    var someComponent = contextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetServices<SomeComponent>(); //service locator pattern
    services.AddMvc(config =>
    {
        config.OutputFormatters.Add(new CustomFormatter(someComponent));
    });
}
```

The above example is for RC2 I notice that in RC1 the key line is a bit different and would be like this:

```
var someComponent = contextAccessor.HttpContext.ApplicationServices.GetService<SomeComponent>();
```

Comment: Sure, I was expecting to have to use this kind of solution, but I just couldn't find the `GetService` call. Also, if I'm not mistaken, I must first create a `ServiceProvider` instance by calling `BuildServiceProvider`, then use that to resolve the service.

Comment: Going through my code, I'm now registering my "custom formatter" as well, so I don't need to call the constructor myself. Later on, I'll see if I can integrate with AutoFac which I'm used to more.

Comment: Sorry I did my original post without confirming that `GetServices` was present where I thought it was.  I have updated my answer to fix my error and provided info on the difference in RC2 and RC1.